# How to get ranks from a sample in a list of values?

Tags: python

I'm new with Python and have a quite simple problem on paper but difficult to me in Python.

I have two samples of values (which are lists) :

```
X = [2, 2, 4, 6]
Y = [1, 3, 4, 5]
```

I have a concatenated list which is sorted as

```
  Z = [ 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 4 , 5 , 6]
 #rank: 1    2.5    4    5.5    7   8
```

I would like to get the sum of ranks of `X` values in `Z`. For this example, the ranks of 2, 2, 4 and 6 in Z are `2.5 + 2.5 + 5.5 + 8 = 18.5`

(ranks of `Y` values in `Z` are `1 + 4 + 5.5 + 7 = 17.5`)

Here is what I've done but it doesn't work with these lists X and Y (it works if each value appears only one time)

```
def funct(X, Z):
    rank = []
    for i in range(len(Z)):
        for j in range(len(X)):
            if Z[i] == X[j]:
                rank = rank + [(i+1)]
    print(sum(rank))
    return
```

I would like to solve my problem with not too much complicated functions (only loops and quite easy ways to get a solution).

Comment: Is this a homework problem? Is that why you don't want it to look too clean?

Comment: Yes it is, not meaning I don't want it to look too clean, I just don't want to use a function that solve the whole problem in one line, is there a solution to just improve my code by adding one or too more loops?

Comment: Unlikely. Just getting the ranks right is going to be a chore. Can you at least use `itertools.groupby`?

Comment: Your code raises an error. Please fix

Comment: Yes sorry it was print(sum(rank)) and not print(sum(r))

Comment: Please observe how I formatted the code in your question. Do that next time as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to keep track of the rank sums and counts once you've sorted the combined list.

```
X = [2, 2, 4, 6]
Y = [1, 3, 4, 5]

Z = sorted(X + Y)

ranksum = {}
counts = {}

for i, v in enumerate(Z):
    ranksum[v] = ranksum.get(v, 0) + (i + 1) # Add
    counts[v] = counts.get(v, 0) + 1 # Increment count
```

Then, when you want to look up the rank of an element, you need `ranksum[v] / count[v]`.

```
r = [ranksum[x] / counts[x] for x in X]
print(r)
# Out: [2.5, 2.5, 5.5, 8]
```

Comment: it does work fine, thank you, i'm quite unfamiliar with dictionnaries but I understood what you've done

Comment: @akben2 dictionaries are pretty useful data structures that save data as a key-value pair, unlike a list which saves data at each index. I recommend looking through some tutorials to understand how and when they should be used. Here's one: https://realpython.com/python-dicts/

Comment: I don't think this calculates the ranks correctly when you have more than two elements with the same value. For example, if you make `X = [2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 6]` the ranks are `[2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 7.5, 10]`, which is not correct.

Comment: @ChrisSears how so? With your input, `Z = [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]`, which means they have the ranks `[1, 2, (3), (4), (5), 6, 7, (8), 9, 10]`, where the ones in parentheses are the duplicates which have fractional rank. The rank for `2` is `2 + 1/4`, the rank for `4` is `7 + 1/2`, and the rank for `6` is `10`.

Comment: Maybe @akben2 could clarify how they want the case of `count > 2` handled - should four twos have the rank `2.25` or `3.5`?

Comment: I understood fractional rank to be the mean of the ordinal ranks of duplicate values. There's an example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking#Fractional_ranking_(%221_2.5_2.5_4%22_ranking)

Comment: @ChrisSears your interpretation makes sense. I'll change my answer when OP clarifies what they want.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, actually the rank for the 4 twos should be 3.5 - I didn't 'approve' your answer Chris because I would like to find a solution without libraries (or packages don't really know how we call that in Python)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for how to build the list of ranks:

```
X = ...
Y = ...
Z = sorted(X + Y)

rank = [1]
z = Z[:1]
for i, e in enumerate(Z[1:], start=2):
    if e == z[-1]:
        rank[-1] += 0.5
    else:
        rank.append(i)
        z.append(e)
```

Now you can convert that into a dictionary:

```
ranks = dict(zip(z, rank))
```

That will make lookup easier:

```
sum(ranks[e] for e in X)
```

Comment: @akben2. Capital `Z` (fixed), but the index is correct. I'm trying to get the first element as a list, not all the remaining elements.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option where you build a dictionary of the rank indexes and then create a rank dictionary from there:

```
from collections import defaultdict

X = [2, 2, 4, 6]
Y = [1, 3, 4, 5]
Z = sorted(X + Y)

rank_indexes = defaultdict(lambda: [])
for i,v in enumerate(Z):
    rank_indexes[v].append(i+1)
ranks = {k:(sum(v)/len(v)) for (k,v) in rank_indexes.items()}

print("Sum of X ranks:", sum([ranks[v] for v in X]))
print("Sum of Y ranks:", sum([ranks[v] for v in Y]))
```

Output:

```
Sum of X ranks: 18.5
Sum of Y ranks: 17.5
```

You can do the same thing without defaultdict, but it's slightly slower and I'd argue less Pythonic:

```
rank_indexes = {}
for i,v in enumerate(Z):
    rank_indexes.setdefault(v, []).append(i+1)
ranks = {k:(sum(v)/len(v)) for (k,v) in rank_indexes.items()}
```